# passing value from php to python

Tags: php, python

I know this has been asked and answered numerous times on this site but I'm still having some trouble.

from bash:
sudo python test1.py blue

test1.py

```html
import sys
who = sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[1]
print who
```

outputs:
blue
blue

from PHP

```html
$ledcolor = "0,255,0";


$result = exec("sudo python test1.py blue"); 
$result = exec("sudo python test1.py" . $ledcolor); 
$result = exec('sudo python test1.py' . $ledcolor); 
$result = exec('sudo python test1.py blue');
```

all result in no output from python
I have also tried shell_exec in PHP with same (no) results.

```html
  $result = exec("sudo python test1.py blue" . $ledcolor); 
  echo "\n";
  print $result;
```

PHP Output = blue0,255,0

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you print `$result`?

Comment: echos only the variable i updated the main post with code and result

Answer (score 0):

In php, the `exec` function passes its full output via a parameter passed by reference :

```
$out = '';
$cmd = exec('/bin/somecommand some parameters', $out);
echo $out;
```

`$cmd` holds the return status of the exec call, not the output.

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec` instead of `exec`, or ` `.

```
$result = `sudo python test1.py blue`;
```